# How to move from UIViewController to SKView and vice versa?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skview

My idea is showing map for few seconds before moving to game scene and the game screens hierarchy is like this: 
GameViewController(**UIViewController**) -> EntryToGameScene (**SKView**) -> MapController (**UIViewController**) -> GamePlayGround (**SKView**)

I'm facing with a problem when moving from MapController to GamePlayGround, to be able to move from controller to scene at first I changed controllers view class to SKView from Storyboard then I added following code ⬇️.After `handleDelay()` method is running, game scene `didMove()` method working but the screen stucking on old view (MapController)!? I'm sure game scene `didMove()` method working because background music starts to play.But why screen is not change?

My code is looks like :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Wait for three sec. then move to game scene
    self.perform(#selector(handleDelay), with: nil, afterDelay: 3.0)
}

@objc fileprivate func handleDelay() {

    view.layoutIfNeeded()

    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene
        let scene = GameScene(size: sceneSize)

        // Set the scale mode
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
        scene.delegate = self
        // Present the scene
        view.presentScene(scene)

        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        view.showsFPS = false
        view.showsNodeCount = false
        view.showsPhysics = false
    }
}
```

All answers acceptable.

Comment: I don't think I fully understand your question. You want to show a map of a dungeon/level in your game for a few seconds before moving to another view? I'm assuming English isn't your first language, but if you could edit your question to better state your problem, that would really help me understand what I need to help you with.

Comment: @E.Huckabee Thank you for your suggestion, I already corrected my quesation.

Comment: @E.Huckabee Yes, you understanded right.

Comment: I would recommend learning how to use your storyboard.  You could storyboard this and not have any code whatsoever.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon can you explain a little more please?

Comment: Nope, you can look up tutorials on storyboarding, it will do a lot better of a job then SO can.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon As you like, in any way thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution with removing all subviews from the view then presenting SKScene.

**Note**: I know its not the best solution but there is no another choise for now, so I changed my code like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.perform(#selector(handleDelay), with: nil, afterDelay: 3.0)

}

@objc fileprivate func handleDelay() {

    self.view.subviews.forEach {$0.removeFromSuperview()}

    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.swift' and should set it's size
        let scene = SecondGameScene(size: self.view.frame.size)
        // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

        // Present the scene
        view.presentScene(scene)

        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        view.showsFPS = false
        view.showsNodeCount = false
    }

}
```

**UPDATE :**
Finally I found right way for moving from SKScene and UIView Controller and vice versa.

For example (Moving from ***SKScene*** to ***UIViewController***):

```
fileprivate func moveToUIViewController(storyBoardId: String) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: storyBoardId)
    vc.view.frame = self.frame
    vc.view.layoutIfNeeded()        

    self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

(Moving from ***UIViewController*** to ***SKScene***):

```
fileprivate func returnToSKScene() {

    for element in self.view.subviews {
        element.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true) {
        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            // Load the SKScene
            var scene: SKScene
            scene = AboutScene(size: sceneSize)

            // Set the scale mode
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            let transition = SKTransition.moveIn(with: .up, duration: 0.2)

            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)

            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            view.showsFPS = false
            view.showsNodeCount = false
            view.showsPhysics = false

        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to change UIViewController *view* class with "SKView":

1. Select view the from Storyboard -> Identity inspector -> Custom class.
2. 2.Select **SKView** from Class dropdown list.

Comment: Figuring out your own problems will help you develop the critical thinking needed to be a developer. Great answer and great job figuring it out on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix. I copied and pasted the code into a test project and I figured out what you had done wrong. You aren't referencing a scene to be presented. You aren't passing in a specific SKView to be presented. You are presenting a generic SKView class.

This code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Wait for three sec. then move to game scene
    self.perform(#selector(handleDelay), with: nil, afterDelay: 3.0)
}

@objc fileprivate func handleDelay() {

    view.layoutIfNeeded()

    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene
        let scene = GameScene(size: sceneSize)

        // Set the scale mode
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
        scene.delegate = self
        // Present the scene
        view.presentScene(scene)

        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        view.showsFPS = false
        view.showsNodeCount = false
        view.showsPhysics = false
    }
}
```

Should look like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Wait for three sec. then move to game scene
    self.perform(#selector(handleDelay), with: nil, afterDelay: 3.0)
}

@objc fileprivate func handleDelay() {

    view.layoutIfNeeded()

    // Load the view as an SKView to prepare for an SKScene
    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene from the GameScene file
        let scene = GameScene()
        // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

        // Present the scene
        view.presentScene(scene)

        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true
    }
}
```

Tested and working.

Comment: But my GameScene is created it without `GameScene.sks` file so how can I give it as reference?

Comment: That bit of code is wrong. I will edit my answer above with the correct code that is functioning like you asked for.

Comment: I noticed but doesnt matter I got the idea, game scene should invoke with name.

Comment: If my answer helped you figure out your problem, you need to accept it as correct. (And maybe drop an up-vote as well) Its so other people who come here will know which answer is the one that helped you.

Comment: I know but you need to edit your answer and also I have to try your solution is correct or not.

Comment: The GameScene won't be invoked with the name. You are setting the name *after* you present the scene. The scene will never be presented because of this. You need to directly reference the SKScene you are trying to present. I edited my answer to provide a method that was working for me and should work for you.

Comment: Screen is changing but old view controller components still remaining on the screen!